# Bootstrap dropdown not trigger at all?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

```
<div class="header-nav">
                        <ul class="nav pull-right" id="testheader1">
                            <li class="dropdown dropdown-hover" id="testheader2">
                                
                                
                                <!-- ajax version -->

                                <a href="#" id="acart" class="header-cart" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <i class="fa fa-shopping-bag"></i>
                                    <span class="total">2</span>
                                    <span class="arrow top"></span>
                                </a>

                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-cart p-0">
                                    <div class="cart-header">
                                        <h4 class="cart-title">Shopping Bag (<span class="cart_total_qty">2</span>) </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="cart-body">
                                        <ul class="cart-item">
                                            
                                                                                                                                                
                                                    <li data-cartid="19" data-proid="62">
                                                        <div class="cart-item-image"><img src="/on.png"></div>
                                                        <div class="cart-item-info">
                                                            <h4>product</h4>
                                                            <p class="price">299.00 x <span class="cart_item_qty">2</span> </p>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="cart-item-close">
                                                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="removefromcart" data-cartid="19" data-proid="62">×</a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </li>

                                                            
                                            
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="cart-footer">
                                        <div class="row row-space-10">
                                            <div class="col-6">
                                            &nbsp;
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-6">
                                                <a href="http://localhost:8000/cart" class="btn btn-inverse btn-theme btn-block">Checkout</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            
                            </li>


                            
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Looking to do some ajax call upon toggle to update the content inside.
Tried with show.bs.dropdown but it taking no effect?

```
$('#acart').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
  alert('open');
  console.log("open");
  $('.dropdown-menu-cart').show();
}); 

$('a[data-toggle="dropdown"]').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
  alert('open');
  console.log("open");
  $('.dropdown-menu-cart').show();
});
```

What do I miss out?

Comment: Your code works Have a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2ernxgtk/).

Comment: i tried, it doesn't work, both not trigger   alert('open');
  console.log("open");

Comment: Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/g21jmLf5/) fiddle .Give id to `parent` of dropdown i.e : `li` and use this selector.

Comment: when using this way to call, the hover toggle auto open won't work anymore. I have to click on it to open, is this a normal behaviour?

Comment: Yes i think so have a look at [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/) but you can write on hover event to achieve same.